# Help - le pronom "en" in Assimil book, lesson 16

Tags: grammaire, en

in Assimil book lesson 16 I read:

> Bonjour, madame. Je cherche un piège à rats. Vous en avez ?

Why not *Vous en avez un ?* I thought that if you use a partitif then you replace "du, de la, des" by "en" as in:

> Il regarde des oiseaux. Il en regarde.

BUT: when using un or une we need to include the number, " quantité", as for example in:

> Il regarde un film. Il en regarde un.

Yet this "un" is missing in my Assimil book... Why?

Answer (score 3):

> *Yet this "un" is missing*

"Un" is missing because "en" is replacing plural. Compare the following:

> Il regarde un film. Il en regarde un.
>
> Il regarde **des films**. Il en regarde.

I understand the confusion because the sentence says "*Je cherche **un** piège à rats*".

But in "*Vous en avez ?*", it's implicitly asking "*Vous avez **des** pièges à rats ?*".

Comment: Ah, thank you, thank you. Indeed, if the sentence was written as you suggested: "Vous avez des ....", I would not be so puzzled by the lack of un. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

With *un*, it's usually better to translate "one". Without, it's better to translate "any".

So here it's the difference between asking "Do you have any?" without *un* and "Do you have one?" with *un*.

In your film example, he watches one particular film (out of the many that exist, *en*).

---

Minor note: for the traps, more natural and less literal might be "Do you carry them?" In English this works with "them" referring to "rat traps", but in French you'd have to say *les* and that would sound like you mean a specific set of rat traps. Hence "Vous en avez ?" would be the natural way to ask "Do you carry them?" as well.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer but you confuse me a bit with LES pièges... Les would require les as COD, wouldn't it? Vous les avez? But then again, why use les if I ask for something for the first time? Writing DES pièges would make me happy. And DES would justify en.... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @user33704 Right, that last part was confusingly written. I meant that since "Vous les avez ?" is impossible here, "Vous en avez ?" would be the natural alternative if you wanted to ask "Do you carry them?"

Comment: No problem :) Thanks again for your help.